# Best time to buy and sell stocks

Tags: python, arrays, dynamic-programming

I'm trying my hand at the Leetcode (121. [Best Time to Buy and Sell Stock](https://leetcode.com/problems/best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stock/)) problem, and the first (brute force) way that popped to my mind was the following code.

I had thought that there wasn't any problem with the logic of the code and that the code's idea looked pretty similar to the official solution, but for some reason, my code got a Memory Limit Exceeded error. I don't want to be using a debugger since in an actual interview setting I won't be able to use one, and I want practice thinking why codes may be wrong just theoretically, but I've been having trouble doing that here. Could someone help me figure out/give me hints as to where I might be erroring?

```
class Solution:
def maxProfit(self, prices: List[int]) -> int:
    
    """
    brute force way:
    for every element in the list, go through every other element after that element and find their 
    differences; store all differences in a single array "profit", and find max
    """
    profit = []
    if len(prices) > 1:
        for i in range(len(prices)):
            for j in range(i+1, len(prices)):
                profit.append(prices[j] - prices[i])
    if len(profit) >= 1:     
        profitt = max(profit)
        return max(0, profitt)
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: I think you are actually not providing the necessary code sample here. What you show is just a class definition, it does **nothing** except describing a class. Now, how do you use this class? What is your logic there? Out of memory exceptions issue occur during loops, or recursive functions, or processing too much data. Without actual program logic, it's impossible to say what your problem might be.

Comment: This question is probably going to be closed, but to maybe give a little helpful advice, you need to study Big-O complexity -- especially relevant when you have nested loops in your code where you don't have upfront heuristics on the input size. The most obvious brute force algorithms often fail -- sometimes spectacularly -- on large input. That's the intuition you need to develop here for this problem.

Comment: Thinking about `Kadane` algorithm here - how to find maxProfit locally in each step.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents (ok, one is not really mine)

- The first inefficiency is storing all the *Profit and Loss* numbers in the list, and then doing another iteration to work out the highest. Just initialize `profit=0` and, every time you see an higher number in those iterations, just set `profit` to that number
- In any case, nested looping is another source of inefficiency here and not necessary. [This is a good explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLV0oLY5-FE&t=408s) how to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

try this answer

```
class Solution:
def maxProfit(self, prices: List[int]) -> int:
    curmax=0
    globalmax=0
    for i in range(1,len(prices)):
        curmax=max(curmax+(prices[i]-prices[i-1]),0)
        globalmax=max(globalmax,curmax)
    return globalmax
```

Comment: Usually a code block with no explanation is not a very good answer. It helps the community much more if you could tell us why we should try this code and why it would/might help the op. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are **Brute force approach** and **Two pointer approach** to solve this problem.

```
Input: prices = [7,1,5,3,6,4]

# Brute force approach
def getMaxProfit1(prices):
    days = len(prices)
    max_profit = prices[0] if days == 1 else 0
    for current_day in range(days):
        for next_day in range(current_day+1, days):
            if prices[current_day] < prices[next_day]:
                profit = prices[next_day] - prices[current_day]
                if profit > max_profit:
                    max_profit = profit
    return max_profit

# Two pointer approach
def getMaxProfit2(prices):
    days = len(prices)
    left_ptr, right_ptr, max_profit = 0, 1, 0

    while right_ptr < days:
        if prices[right_ptr] > prices[left_ptr]:
            profit = prices[right_ptr] - prices[left_ptr]
            max_profit = max(max_profit, profit)
        else:
            left_ptr = right_ptr
        right_ptr += 1

    return max_profit

Output: 5
Explanation: Buy on day 2 (price = 1) and sell on day 5 (price = 6), profit = 6-1 = 5
```

Time complexity:

- Brute force: O(N²)
- Two pointer: O(N)